# Get text between brackets regex and not text with quotes

Tags: regex

I have following text for which I am trying to create a regex:

```
test the error Error: element (".homeScreen .screen_title .title")
 still not visible after 30000msF0 passing (37.80s)1 failing1) Guidesuite1 can favorite any channel C966872:Failed: element (".homeScreen
 .screen_title .title") still not visible after 30000msrunning chromeerror properties: Object({ details: undefined, type: 'WaitUntilTimeoutError'
, shotTaken: true })Error: element (".homeScreen .screen_title .title") 
still not visible after 30000ms at elements(".homeScreen .screen_title 
.title") - isVisible.js:54:17 at isVisible(".homeScreen .screen_title .title") - waitForVisible.js:73:22Wrote json report to [./].
```

I want a regex that grabs only (37.80s).

My current solution is to use `(\(.*?\))`.

But this returns 3 matches. How can Ijust get the required group?

Comment: my first try was this: `\(\d{2}\.\d{2}s\)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regexp :

```
/(\([^"')]+\))/gm
```

Working fiddle : [here](https://regex101.com/r/bMikuw/2)

Answer (score 0):

You could also try: `\(((?!").*?(?<!"))\)`.

It uses negative lookahead `(?!")` to fetermine that what follows opening bracket isn't double qoute `"`.

Also it uses negative lookbehind `(?<!")` to assure that what preceed closing bracket also isn't double quote.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ku17lq/1)